# How to filter the following list using Lodash `_.filter()`

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have the following list named cart:

```
cart = [ {"state": "Canada", "id": "1"}, {"state": "USA", "id": "1"} ]
```

I have tried filtering it according to the following code where state should either be (USA, Canada),  but its giving errors:

```
var oddNo = _.filter(cart, {'state': {"Canada", "USA"}, 'id': "1"});
console.log(oddNo);
```

What would be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: This question would be better with some extra details to let us know what is going on. Tell us which library you're using (is it underscore?), and also paste the errors you are getting. Otherwise we're left guessing as to what your issue actually is.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/underscore-js-_-filter-with-examples/ ( This is the one )

cc @KenWayneVanderLinde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm guessing this is loadash or underscore? the easiest way will be to pass a function as the second parameter that filters the array.
`_.filter(cart, (items) => {return item.state === 'USA' || item.state ==='Canada'})`
check out the docs on lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter

although really you probably dont need lodash for this and can just use native js filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter